# What is the most suitable "Want" or "Need"

Tags: meaning, differences

When I send an email to a seller, I can express,

**1.**
I want to buy ....

**2.**
I need to buy ....

What is the most suitable one? What are the differences between "Want" and "Need" ?

Comment: Did you look up both words in a dictionary? If doing so doesn’t solve your problem please edit your question with the definitions you found and explain what you don’t understand.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research/ELL"). Hi NSiri, our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Want** means to have a strong desire for. In your sentence, **I want to buy smth**, you practically say that you wish to buy smth.

**Need** means to be in need of, to require. Your sentence, **I need to buy smth**, suggests that it is imperative (necessary) for you to buy that object. It's not only a wish, but a vital requirement to buy it.

Answer (score -1):

The difference in the two words is ***urgency***, with subtext of ***importance***.

If you want something you don't need it currently, but would like it *eventually*.
It doesn't matter how long it takes to reach the end result, as long as you eventually get it. If someone "wants" the reports on their desk by Monday, it means that it's encouraged for you to do so, but not absolutely required.

If you *need* something it means that is imperative that you have it as soon as possible. It is very important that you have it as soon as possible. You require it. If someone "needs" the reports on their desk by Monday, their task likely hinges on those reports being there by a specific date. It is urgent, and important that they are there.